# Mutiple quotation marks in HTML / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, quotation-marks

Sorry for the stupid question. I tried looking for an answer somewhere, but couldn't find any. I can't get this code to work:

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage = 'url('#')'";>
</div>
```

Help?

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve, can you please elaborate

Comment: I'm trying to make the div change to a different background on mouseover. The # is not the actual link for the picture.

Comment: In case of url you need not use the string quotes for the url try `<div onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(someurl)'";>
</div>`

Answer (score 3):

Escape single quotes:

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'#\')'">
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I tried at first, but it didn't work. Weird.

Comment: nvm Thank you so much!